# How to reverse a string in R

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to teach myself R and in doing some sample problems I came across the need to reverse a string.

Here's what I've tried so far but the paste operation doesn't seem to have any effect.

There must be something I'm not understanding about lists?  (I also don't understand why I need the [[1]] after strsplit.)

```r
test <- strsplit("greg", NULL)[[1]]
test
# [1] "g" "r" "e" "g"

test_rev <- rev(test)
test_rev
# [1] "g" "e" "r" "g"

paste(test_rev)
# [1] "g" "e" "r" "g"
```

Comment: You're looking for `paste(test_rev, collapse='')`.

Comment: Thanks.  Why is collapse required?

Comment: That's the behavior of `paste`. Check out the documentation. If `x` and `y` are two string variables, `paste(x,y)` and `paste(c(x, y))` give different results. You probably expected them to be the same.

Comment: @mplourde The way I think about it that it allows for `paste` to behave in a vectorized manner like most other R functions.

Comment: @joran Yeah, thank goodness we don't have to write `do.call(paste, as.list(my.atomic))`.

Comment: Seems that http://xkcd.com/1137/  is appropriate here :-)

Comment: To better understand why you need the `[[1]]` after `strsplit()`, try running this: `X <- strsplit(c("abc", "Statistics"), NULL); X; X[[1]]; X[[2]]`

Comment: Google says: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/reverse-string-td2288532.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As @mplourde points out, you want the `collapse` argument:

```
paste(test_rev, collapse='')
```

Most commands in R are vectorized, but how exactly the command handles vectors depends on the command.  `paste` will operate over multiple vectors, combining the `i`th element of each:

```
> paste(letters[1:5],letters[1:5])
[1] "a a" "b b" "c c" "d d" "e e"
```

`collapse` tells it to operate within a vector instead.

Comment: So why would I write collapse=''?  Wouldn't the '' evaluate to false?  Shouldn't I be saying collapse=True?  (Still learning my R basics)

Comment: @Greg `paste` is a bit non-standard, and I think your intuition is perfectly R-like.  However, in this case, `,collapse` works like `,sep` in that it specifies a character to insert in the final character vector.  Try `paste(test_rev, collapse='Whee!')` for an illustration.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman After collapsing it with `paste`, I get `"c(\"l\", \"o\", \"o\", \"c\")"`. But the string was `cool` Whats wrong?

Answer (score 55):

From `?strsplit`, a function that'll reverse every string in a vector of strings:

```
## a useful function: rev() for strings
strReverse <- function(x)
        sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, NULL), rev), paste, collapse="")
strReverse(c("abc", "Statistics"))
# [1] "cba"        "scitsitatS"
```

Comment: Nice, same function rewritten the dplyr/[magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) way for readability `strreverse <- function(x){ strsplit(x, NULL) %>% lapply(rev) %>% sapply(paste, collapse="") }`.

Answer (score 41):

`stringi` has had this function for quite a long time:

```
stringi::stri_reverse("abcdef")
## [1] "fedcba"
```

Also note that it's vectorized:

```
stringi::stri_reverse(c("a", "ab", "abc"))
## [1] "a"   "ba"  "cba"
```

Comment: This reverses characters, not strings.

Answer (score 10):

The following can be a useful way to reverse a vector of strings `x`, and is slightly faster (and more memory efficient) because it avoids generating a list (as in using `strsplit`):

```
x <- rep( paste( collapse="", LETTERS ), 100 )
str_rev <- function(x) {
  sapply( x, function(xx) { 
    intToUtf8( rev( utf8ToInt( xx ) ) )
  } )
}
str_rev(x)
```

If you know that you're going to be working with ASCII characters and speed matters, there is a fast C implementation for reversing a vector of strings built into `Kmisc`:

```
install.packages("Kmisc")
str_rev(x)
```

Comment: even faster would be `str_rev <- function(x) intToUtf8(rev(utf8ToInt(x)))` and to vectorize it (what your `sapply` does), do str_rev <- Vectorize(str_rev) (but it uses `mapply` under the hood). Are you sure, that `sapply` does not create a list as a intermediate product? Definitely, it is faster than `strsplit`. Nice trick with `utf8ToInt` and `intToUtf8` - thank you! and `rev`.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the `IRanges` package.

```
library(IRanges)
x <- "ATGCSDS"
reverse(x)
# [1] "SDSCGTA"
```

You can also use the `Biostrings` package.

```
library(Biostrings)
x <- "ATGCSDS"
reverse(x)
# [1] "SDSCGTA"
```

Answer (score 6):

If your data is in a `data.frame`, you can use `sqldf`:

```
myStrings <- data.frame(forward = c("does", "this", "actually", "work"))
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select forward, reverse(forward) `reverse` from myStrings")
#    forward  reverse
# 1     does     seod
# 2     this     siht
# 3 actually yllautca
# 4     work     krow
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a function that returns the whole reversed string, or optionally the reverse string keeping only the elements specified by `index`, counting backward from the last character.

```
revString = function(string, index = 1:nchar(string)){
  paste(rev(unlist(strsplit(string, NULL)))[index], collapse = "")
}
```

First, define an easily recognizable string as an example:

`(myString <- paste(letters, collapse = ""))`

`[1] "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`

Now try out the function `revString` with and without the index:

`revString(myString)`

`[1] "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"`

`revString(myString, 1:5)`

`[1] "zyxwv"`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to reverse string:

```
#reverse string----------------------------------------------------------------
revString <- function(text){
  paste(rev(unlist(strsplit(text,NULL))),collapse="")
}

#example:
revString("abcdef")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do with rev() function as mentioned in a previous post.

```
`X <- "MyString"
```

`RevX <- paste(rev(unlist(strsplit(X,NULL))),collapse="")`

Output : "gnirtSyM"

Thanks,

Comment: There is no point in answering 5 year old questions, with 25000 views already. Your answer will be buried somewhere no one will see. Instead answer the latest questions

Comment: Nothing wrong with answering old questions. I can see his answer just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The following Code will take input from user and reverse the entire string-

```
revstring=function(s)
print(paste(rev(strsplit(s,"")[[1]]),collapse=""))

str=readline("Enter the string:")
revstring(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `gsub`. Although I agree that it's easier with `strsplit` and `paste` (as pointed out in the other answers), it may be interesting to see that it works with regular expressions too:

```
test <- "greg"

n <- nchar(test) # the number of characters in the string

gsub(paste(rep("(.)", n), collapse = ""),
     paste("", seq(n, 1), sep = "\\", collapse = ""),
     test)

# [1] "gerg"
```

Comment: @mvkorpel This is true. It is more a demonstration of the concept, not a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
##function to reverse the given word or sentence

reverse <- function(mystring){ 
n <- nchar(mystring)
revstring <- rep(NA, n)
b <- n:1
c <- rev(b)
for (i in 1:n) {
revstring[i] <- substr(mystring,c[(n+1)- i], b[i])
 }
newrevstring <- paste(revstring, sep = "", collapse = "")
return (cat("your string =", mystring, "\n",
("reverse letters = "), revstring, "\n", 
"reverse string =", newrevstring,"\n"))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more base-R solution:

```
# Define function
strrev <- function(x) {
  nc <- nchar(x)
  paste(substring(x, nc:1, nc:1), collapse = "")
}

# Example
strrev("Sore was I ere I saw Eros")
[1] "sorE was I ere I saw eroS"
```

Solution was inspired by [these U. Auckland slides](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~stats380/downloads/02-Palindromes-handouts.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

So apparently front-end JS developers get asked to do this (for interviews) in JS without using built-in reverse functions. It took me a few minutes, but I came up with:

```
string <- 'hello'

foo <- vector()

for (i in nchar(string):1) foo <- append(foo,unlist(strsplit(string,''))[i])
paste0(foo,collapse='')
```

Which all could be wrapped in a function...

What about higher-order functionals? Reduce?

Comment: Much more efficient to use `rev` or a library's string function.