# reverse elements in each col of a matrix without reversing col order

Tags: r

Using R, I want to reverse all the elements in each column, for a single row of a matrix. I can get the row order to reverse (which is not what I want), but not the elements in the rows.

**create example matrix**

```
snips <- c("CCA", "ATC", "TTC")
row2 <- 1:3
my.matrix <- as.matrix(rbind(snips, row2))
my.matrix

[,1]  [,2]  [,3] 

snips "CCA" "ATC" "TTC"
row2  "1"   "2"   "3"
```

**reverse the elements in the row = snips**

```
my.matrix.reversed <- rev(my.matrix[my.matrix[1,], ])
```

> Error in my.matrix[my.matrix[1, ], ] : subscript out of bounds

what I want to get is:

```
[,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
snips "ACC" "CTA" "CTT"
row2  "1"   "2"   "3"
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use one of the string manipulation packages, like "stringi" to reverse the strings:

```
library(stringi)
my.matrix[1, ] <- stri_reverse(my.matrix[1, ])
my.matrix
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
# snips "ACC" "CTA" "CTT"
# row2  "1"   "2"   "3"
```

Comment: thanks! stringi did exactly what I needed it to do.

Answer (score 0):

We may need some string manipulation.  Assuming there are only 3 characters in the original dataset, we can capture each character as a group (`(.)`) in `sub` and reverse the order of capture groups (`\3\2\1')

```
my.matrix[1,] <- sub("(.)(.)(.)", "\\3\\2\\1", my.matrix[1,])
my.matrix
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
#snips "ACC" "CTA" "CTT"
#row2  "1"   "2"   "3"
```

A more generalized approach would be to split the string into individual characters, then `rev` and `paste` it back

```
my.matrix[1,] <- sapply(strsplit(my.matrix[1,], ""), function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse=""))
```

---

Or using `Biostrings`

```
library(Biostrings)
my.matrix[1,] <- reverse(my.matrix[1,])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `stringi::stri_reverse`. This code assumes that the only other row is `row2` and it contains only single characters, so reversal doesn't matter. If that isn't the case you need to apply the function to only the `snips` row.

```
library(stringi)
apply(my.matrix, 1:2, function(x) stri_reverse(x))

       [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
snips "ACC" "CTA" "CTT"
row2  "1"   "2"   "3"
```

Lots of other solutions [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612967/how-to-reverse-a-string-in-r).