# r Format numbers with 0 and dashes

Tags: r, number-formatting

I am dealing with numbers like this below

```
   12344
  233345
 7233433
 9343883
 3432837
```

I am trying to format these number such that they all are of same length and dash (-) after every three numbers. The final expected results should like this below.

```
  0-012-344
  0-233-345
  7-233-433
  9-343-883
  3-432-837
```

Any help on formatting these numbers this way is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `formatC`:

```
formatC(x, width = 7, format = "d", flag = "0", big.mark = '-')
# [1] "0-012-344" "0-233-345" "7-233-433" "9-343-883" "3-432-837"
```

The data used:

```
x <- scan(textConnection('12344
233345
7233433
9343883
3432837'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution,

```
my_format <- function(num){
x <- sprintf("%07d", num)
paste0(substr(x, 1,1), "-",
    substr(x, 2,4), "-",
    substr(x, 5,7))
}

nums <-  c(12344,233345,7233433,9343883,3432837)
my_format(nums)

# gives
[1] "0-012-344" "0-233-345" "7-233-433" "9-343-883" "3-432-837"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `stringr` and `purrr`.

```
# Data
numbers <- c("12344", "233345", "7233433", "9343883", "3432837")

# Load package
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

# A function to add dash line
trans_num <- function(number){
  part1 <- str_sub(number, start = 1, end = 1)
  part2 <- str_sub(number, start = 2, end = 4)
  part3 <- str_sub(number, start = 5)
  return(paste(part1, part2, part3, sep = "-"))
}

numbers %>%
  str_pad(width = 7, pad = "0") %>%
  map_chr(trans_num)
[1] "0-012-344" "0-233-345" "7-233-433" "9-343-883" "3-432-837"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base R` option with `sub` and `sprintf`

```
sub("(.)(.{3})", '\\1-\\2-', sprintf("%07d", x))
#[1] "0-012-344" "0-233-345" "7-233-433" "9-343-883" "3-432-837"
```

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to build your strings of length seven with leading zeroes.  I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612967/how-to-reverse-a-string-in-r):

```
strReverse <- function(x)
    sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, NULL), rev), paste, collapse="")

v = as.character(read.table(text = "   12344
  233345
 7233433
 9343883
 3432837", header = FALSE)[,1])

v1 = strReverse( substring(paste0(strReverse(v), "0000"), 1, 7))
```

Result:

```
> v1
[1] "0012344" "0233345" "7233433" "9343883" "3432837"
```

Adding dashes should be straightforward, now:

```
paste0(substring(v1,1,1), "-", substring(v1,2,4), "-", substring(v1,5,7))
```